# using iterator in ostream fails

Tags: c++, arrays, stdlist

I am attempting to implement a std::list to replace a linked list in this assignment. I am not allowed to change the declarations and can only change code in the .cpp file. For the most part I am making progress but I am having trouble implementing this

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Section& section);
```

namely when I try to create an iterator it fails. I've used the iterator elsewhere in the code so I don't understand why it's failing here, I believe it's because it's private but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue without changing the .h file which was explicitly prohibited:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Section& section)
{
  // 1. print the section header
  out << setw(8) << left << section.getCourse()
      << setw(6) << left << section.getCallNumber();
  out << ": " << section.getNumberOfStudents() << " students\n";

  // 2. collect the students, sort, and print
  Student* students = new Student[section.getNumberOfStudents()];
  {
    int i = 0;

    for ( auto pos = section.students.begin();
     pos != section.students.end(); pos++)
      {
    students[i] = pos;
    ++i;
      }
  }

  sort (students, students+section.getNumberOfStudents());

  for (int i = 0; i < section.getNumberOfStudents(); ++i)
    out << "    " << students[i] << "\n";

  out << flush;
  return out;
}
```

Comment: The new list type has no public method for element-by-element access at all?

Comment: I think I have the answer, but I've delete it until I can confirm that `section.students.begin()` returns `std::list::Iterator<Student>`.

Comment: `section` is const, so you probably want `section.students.cbegin()` and `section.students.cend()`.

Comment: @user4581301 yes it does. in my copy constructor I use it like this and this seems to work:

 auto pos = sect.students.begin();

 students.clear();
    while (pos != sect.students.end())
    {
       students.push_back(*pos);
       ++pos;
    }

but within << I get  an error

Comment: @Addy: In your copy constructor, you are dereferencing the iterator being copied from (`*pos`), but in your `operator<<` you are not dereferencing (`= pos` instead of `= *pos`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
students[i] = pos;
```

should be changed to

```
students[i] = *pos;
```

because you want to copy the `Student` the iterator references, not the iterator itself.

But why a dynamic array of `Student` rather than a `std::vector<Student>`? Currently you have a memory leak because you don't `delete[] students;`

## Edit 1

Removed.

## Edit 2

Other than that, all I can see that it wrong is a missing `std::` in front of

```
sort (students, students+section.getNumberOfStudents());
```

this is assuming there is no custom `sort` method being used.

## Edit 3

Going off the rails here:

```
students[i] = *pos;
```

copies a Student from the `list` into the dynamic array `students`. This could be expensive, so here is an alternative:

First the bits and pieces needed to prove this out: Required includes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
```

a minimal Student class

```
class Student
{
    std::string name; 
public:
    Student(std::string inname):name(inname)
    {

    }
    const std::string & getname() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    friend bool operator<(const Student & a, const Student &b)
    {
        return a.name < b.name;
    }
};
```

a minimal Section class

```
class Section
{
public:
    std::list<Student> students;
};
```

a minimal outstream operator

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Section& section)
{
```

A `std::vector` instead of an array, and a vector of constant references so we don't have to copy the students.

```
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const Student>> students;
```

Store references in the `vector`. Probably could do a one liner with `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter`, but this is getting a bit too much to absorb for one example.

```
    for (const auto & student: section.students)
    {
        students.push_back(std::ref(student));
    }
```

Sort the `vector`

```
    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end());
```

print the `vector`

```
    for (const auto & student: students)
    {
        out << student.get().getname() << " ";
    }
    return out;
}
```

and one `main` to rule them all and in the darkness bind them

```
int main()
{
    Section s;

    s.students.emplace_front("Tom");
    s.students.emplace_front("Dick");
    s.students.emplace_front("Harry");
    std::cout << s;
}
```

And all in one easy to cut-n-paste block:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class Student
{
public:
    std::string name; // this is me being lazy. name should be private
    Student(std::string inname):name(inname)
    {

    }
    const std::string & getname() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    friend bool operator<(const Student & a, const Student &b)
    {
        return a.name < b.name;
    }
};

class Section
{
public:
    std::list<Student> students;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Section& section)
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const Student>> students;

    // store references in the `vector`.
    for (const auto & student: section.students)
    {
        students.push_back(std::ref(student));
    }

     // Sort the `vector`
    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end());

    // print the `vector`
    for (const auto & student: students)
    {
        out << student.get().getname() << " ";
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Section s;

    s.students.emplace_front("Tom");
    s.students.emplace_front("Dick");
    s.students.emplace_front("Harry");
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Or do what Remy suggested and use a `std::vector<Student *>` and a custom comparator to dereference the pointers for `std::sort`.

Comment: hrm still no dice. I'm not attached to using an array, he mentioned we should model it after the existing << from a previous lab so I used that as a starting point. changing pos to *pos had no effect.  I should mention the errors I get are "within this context," but section.h's std::list<Student> students; declaration complains that "'std::list<Student> Section::students' is private"  anytime I try to create an iterator. I'm just not sure how to access the student list from operator<< without changing it's declaration.

Comment: as for const issues the iterators are declared as such in the .h so wouldn't auto handle using the correct version or am I misunderstanding how auto works?

`iterator begin();`
  `const_iterator begin() const;`

Comment: You got us on the const iterator. Didn't know the compiler could select an overload on `const`, but I probably should have. It's selecting based on a a `const TYPE * this` parameter.

Comment: The first bit is still correct. `auto` in `auto pos` is standing in for `std::list<Student>::const_iterator`, and that cannot be assigned to a `Student`. You need to get to the `iterator`'s `Student` with `*`.

Comment: The loop that populates the array can be replaced with a `std::vector` and `std::copy()`, eg: `std::vector<Student> students; students.reserve(section.getNumberOfStudents()); std::copy(section.cbegin(), section.cend(), std::back_inserter(students));` However, depending on how complex `Student` is, making a hard copy of each `Student` may be a lot of overhead for `operator<<`, so I would actually use a `std::vector<Student*>` instead, populate with pointers to the original `Student`s in `section`, and then use a custom comparer with `std::sort()`, thus avoiding making any copies at all.

Comment: Holy expletive deleted. Here I am working up this example with `std::reference_wrapper<const Student>>` to get around the copying and I could have just used a pointer. I hang my head in shame. Learned a lot about `std::ref`, but Crom....

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the error is because you are not dereferencing the iterator when populating your `students[]` array:

```
students[i] = pos; // <-- should be *pos instead!
```

I would suggest an alternative approach that should be faster and more efficient:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Section& section)
{
  // 1. print the section header
  out << setw(8) << left << section.getCourse()
      << setw(6) << left << section.getCallNumber();
  out << ": " << section.getNumberOfStudents() << " students\n";

  // 2. collect the students, sort, and print
  std::vector<const Student*> students;
  students.reserve(section.getNumberOfStudents());

  for ( auto pos = section.students.cbegin();
    pos != section.students.cend(); ++pos)
  {
      students.push_back(&(*pos));
  }

  sort (students.begin(), students.end(), 
    [](const Student *a, const Student *b) { return (*a < *b); }
  );

  for ( auto pos = students.cbegin();
    pos != students.cend(); ++pos)
  {
    out << "    " << *(*pos) << "\n";
  }

  out << flush;
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all your answers. Ended up being a much more basic issue. I had to implement the Section iterators to return student iterators.

```
    Section::iterator Section::begin() {
    return students.begin();
}

Section::const_iterator Section::begin() const {
    return students.begin();
}

Section::iterator Section::end() {
    return students.begin();
}

Section::const_iterator Section::end() const {
    return students.begin();
}
```